# Casting Generic 2d array Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, casting

I'm getting an error trying to cast a generic 2d array, any tips?

```
    public E[][] multiplyMatrix(E[][] matrix1, E[][] matrix2) {

    // Check bounds
    if (matrix1[0].length != matrix2.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "The matrices do not have compatible size");
    }

    // Create result matrix
    E[][] result = (E[][])new Object[matrix1.length][matrix2[0].length];

    // Perform multiplication of two matrices
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
            result[i][j] = zero();

            for (int k = 0; k < matrix1[0].length; k++) {
                result[i][j] = plus(result[i][j],
                        multiply(matrix1[i][k], matrix2[k][j]));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is my error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Double;
```

Comment: E[][] result = (E[][])new Double[matrix1.length][matrix2[0].length]; try this, I did not tried it, its a wild guess

Comment: It would help if you provided the missing methods (multiply, zero,plus). Also, where in the code is the error coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
(E[][])new Object[matrix1.length][matrix2[0].length]
```

I'm guessing somewhere you have something like this:

```
Double[][] result = multiplyMatrix(m1, m2); // m1 & m2 are also Double[][]
```

So you'll have to tell me if you think the following would be a good idea:

```
(Double[][])new Object[n][n]
```

If you agree that seems like a bad idea, then you understand why you're getting an exception, except that the unchecked cast obfuscates what's going on.

You need to use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) or [`getComponentType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--)/[`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int...-) if you want to create an array generically with the correct type. This doesn't totally solve the problem though, because there's nothing stopping you from calling `multiplyMatrix` with incompatible array arguments. Try this to see what I mean:

```
multiplyMatrix(new Double[1][1], new Integer[1][1]);
```

Personally I'd recommend just not trying to do math generically because generics aren't designed for it and it's fraught with more pitfalls. Or maybe use an existing library since I'm pretty sure there are a few out there.